# f# iterate and use List<List<string>>

Tags: list, f#

I have simple list that contains inside list

```
let ftss = [
  ["a","aData"],["b","bData"]
]
```

I want to iterate and access the elements "a" and "aData" etc.

I tried

```
List.iter (fun item ->
    for i in 0..1 do 
        printfn "%s" item[i])
```

how do i access the elements inside the internal list?
Thanks

Comment: List elements are separated with semicolons, not commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, 1st thing is a comma isnt a delimter in a list, but in a tuple ',' so

```
let ftss = [
  ["a","aData"],["b","bData"]
]
```

is actually of type

```
val ftss: ((string * string) list * (string * string) list) list =
```

i.e. its a list of 1 entry of a tuple of a list of 1 entry each of a tuple.
which I THINK isnt what you intended?

I THINK you want (a ';' or new line delimits each entry)

```
let ftss3 = [
  ["a";"aData"]
  ["b";"bData"]
]
```

which is

```
val ftss3: string list list = [["a"; "aData"]; ["b"; "bData"]]
```

i.e. a list of a list of strings.

(I'd try to use FSI to enter these things in, and see what the types are)

so to iterate this list of lists you would go

```
List.iter (fun xs -> 
    List.iter  (fun x -> 
        printfn "%s" x)
        xs)
    ftss3
```

Comment: Thank you  for a clear answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the existing answer, you probably want to represent your data as a list of lists, for which you need to use the `;` delimiter (to make a list) rather than `,` to construct a singleton containing a tuple.

I would just add that if you want to perform an imperative action with each of the items, such as printing, then it is perfectly reasonable to use an ordinary `for` loop:

```
let ftss = [
  ["a"; "aData"]; ["b"; "bData"]
] 

for nested in ftss do 
  for item in nested do 
    printfn "%s" item
```